# How to run 2 different applications in different timezones in Cloud Servers

Tags: java, date

My Server time is in UTC Format. One of my application needs to run in CST time zone and another in UTC Time zone. I try to use SimpleDateFormat and  set the Time Zone to CST but its affecting another application which is running on the same Server. Could any one help me how to run the particular application is CST format ? is there any possibility??